# How to reload grid after every 5 seconds in angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using angular js and using and I want to reload grid after every 5 seconds.

My angular js code for build grid is as bellow:

```
App.controller('NGTableCtrl', NGTableCtrl);

function NGTableCtrl($scope, $filter, ngTableParams, $resource, $timeout, ngTableDataService) {
  'use strict';
  // required for inner references
  var vm = this;
  var data = [
  {name: "Moroni",  age: 50, money: -10   },
  {name: "Tiancum", age: 43, money: 120   },
  {name: "Jacob",   age: 27, money: 5.5   },
  {name: "Nephi",   age: 29, money: -54   },
  {name: "Enos",    age: 34, money: 110   },
  {name: "Tiancum", age: 43, money: 1000  },
  {name: "Jacob",   age: 27, money: -201  },
  {name: "Nephi",   age: 29, money: 100   },
  {name: "Enos",    age: 34, money: -52.5 },
  {name: "Tiancum", age: 43, money: 52.1  },
  {name: "Jacob",   age: 27, money: 110   },
  {name: "Nephi",   age: 29, money: -55   },
  {name: "Enos",    age: 34, money: 551   },
  {name: "Tiancum", age: 43, money: -1410 },
  {name: "Jacob",   age: 27, money: 410   },
  {name: "Nephi",   age: 29, money: 100   },
  {name: "Enos",    age: 34, money: -100  }
 ];
 // SELECT ROWS
 vm.data = data;
 vm.tableParams3 = new ngTableParams({
  page: 1,            // show first page
  count: 10          // count per page
  }, {
  total: data.length, // length of data
  getData: function ($defer, params) {
      // use build-in angular filter
      var filteredData = params.filter() ?
              $filter('filter')(data, params.filter()) :
              data;
      var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
              $filter('orderBy')(filteredData, params.orderBy()) :
              data;

      params.total(orderedData.length); // set total for recalc pagination
      $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
  }
});

// EXPORT CSV
  var data4 = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
  {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
  {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
  {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
  {name: "Enos", age: 34},
  {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
  {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
  {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
  {name: "Enos", age: 34},
  {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
  {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
  {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
  {name: "Enos", age: 34},
  {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
  {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
  {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
  {name: "Enos", age: 34}];

  vm.tableParams4 = new ngTableParams({
  page: 1,            // show first page
  count: 10           // count per page
  }, {
  total: data4.length, // length of data4
  getData: function($defer, params) {
      $defer.resolve(data4.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
  }
  });


  // SORTING
  vm.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
  page: 1,            // show first page
  count: 10,          // count per page
  sorting: {
      name: 'asc'     // initial sorting
  }
  }, {
  total: data.length, // length of data
  getData: function($defer, params) {
      // use build-in angular filter
      var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
              $filter('orderBy')(data, params.orderBy()) :
              data;

      $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
  }
  });

  // FILTERS
  vm.tableParams2 = new ngTableParams({
  page: 1,            // show first page
  count: 10,          // count per page
  filter: {
      name: '',
      age: ''
      // name: 'M'       // initial filter
  }
  }, {
  total: data.length, // length of data
  getData: function($defer, params) {
      // use build-in angular filter
      var orderedData = params.filter() ?
             $filter('filter')(data, params.filter()) :
             data;

      vm.users = orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());

      params.total(orderedData.length); // set total for recalc pagination
      $defer.resolve(vm.users);
  }
  });

  }
```

If I am using setTimeout inside the function then it is not refreshing new values.

Any help/suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: use $timeout instead of setTimeout

Comment: where exactly do you want to reload this grid, set up timer in controller?

Comment: Function NGTableCtrl(....) itself want to reload then where we need to put the $timeout code?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure exactly which function you need to wrap and execute every 5 seconds, but you can use the Angular [Interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) service.

Simply inject `$interval` to your controller and do this:

```
$interval(functionToRerun, 5000);
```

This way it will rerun your function every 5 seconds.

A quick note on why setTimeout didn't refresh the values on the view: `setTimeout` is not an Angular function, so Angular was not aware of the change, hence the $digest cycle did not run and the changes were not reflected.

Comment: You are right about difference between setinterval and $interval, however in OP's case it doesn't matter, since `functionToRerun` triggers digest itself.

Comment: @dfsq I might have missed that line of code, where do you see it triggering the digest ? Do you know which function he wants to rerun ?

Comment: In order to reload `ngTable` grid one would call `tableParams.reload` method, which would call corresponding `getData` method internally. Which in its turn uses `$defer.resolve`. Anyway `$interval` doesn't hurt either :)

Comment: @dfsq Oh ok, wasn't aware of that chain :)

Comment: Function NGTableCtrl(....) itself want to reload then where we need to put the $interval code?

Answer (score 1):

Try.. `$interval`

```
$interval(function () {
    loadData();
}, duration)
```

More about this at.. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval